# $ fyne package -os linux ... RESULT is: bash: fyne: command not found

Tags: go, fyne

After having coded and built my first app using the fyne toolkit, the next task is distribution. Following the instructions at https://developer.fyne.io/started/packaging

The command "**fyne package -os linux -icon myapp.png**" only produces "**bash: fyne: command not found**"

It would seem that there is a missing directory in my $PATH or $GOPATH variables or some other place that it needs to be, so that the 'fyne' cmd-tool can be found.

While my experience with the fyne toolkit has been very productive and enjoyable otherwise (been able to puzzle out every other difficulty) this issue has bested me.

Please, please, somebody help me!
Maybe I'm just blind to what I cannot see. ;)

My app is beautiful (*of course it is, everyone thinks their work is beautiful*), but it's all for nothing if it can't be distributed. What will it matter if nobody ever gets to use it? Ugh, to be so close, yet sooooo far.

Answer (score 2):

My version is gov1.18 and the above answer does not solve my problem. I use `go insall`  instead of `go get`

Answer (score 0):

You need $GOPATH/bin in your $PATH. Sometimes the Go installer does not do this, and sometimes you just need to close the terminal or log out and try it again.

Comment: Thank you andy-dot-xyz. You are an asset to the fyne community. I have relied on many of your posts and answers as I have learned the fyne toolkit.

Comment: Next issue: Adding $GOPATH/bin was an easy fix and has the command working, but now it fails with this message: "unable to build directory to expected executable". Yes I have set permissions (read/write/create), and it deletes the directory if it is already there (showing it is not a perms problem), so what could be the issue?

Comment: Not the most helpful error message I guess - it means the build executable did not have the expected name. You may need to share more info, consider a new question or opening an issue on GitHub.